# Arrays, inheritance, generics

Tags: c#

I had a requirement where I need to create object using same interface but one derived class expects simple data and other array of type. Here is solution I came up with:

I had two questions:

1. As you can see I am converting `IEquatable<T>` into `T`. In my testing so far I did not see any disasters. Can you think of any from top off your head?
2. Is there a way I can change constraint in `ArrayExpectant::CloneFromMe` to `ArrayWrapper` instead of `IEquatable`?

```
public class ArrayWrapper<T> : IEquatable<T>
{
    public T[] Array { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(T other) { return false;  }
    public bool Equals(T[] other) { return Array == other; }
    public bool Equals(ArrayWrapper<T> other) { return Array == other.Array; }
}

public interface ICreationByCloning
{
    ICreated CloneFromMe<TClone>(IEquatable<TClone> t) where TClone : IEquatable<TClone>;
}

public interface ICreated { }

public class Simpleton<T> : ICreated, ICreationByCloning  
{
    public Simpleton(T t) { }
    public ICreated CloneFromMe<TClone>(IEquatable<TClone> t) where TClone : IEquatable<TClone>
    {
        return new Simpleton<TClone>((TClone)t); 
    }  
}

public class ArrayExpectant<T> : ICreated, ICreationByCloning where T : IEquatable<T>
{

    T[] Data { get; set; }
    public ArrayExpectant(T[] t) { Data = t; }
    public ICreated CloneFromMe<TClone>(IEquatable<TClone> t) where TClone : IEquatable<TClone>
    {
        TClone[] array = (t as ArrayWrapper<TClone>).Array;

        return new ArrayExpectant<TClone>(array); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are building the interface, why not build always an array and check for the quantity of data?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve with this code. Could you show us, how would you use it with both `Simpleton` and `ArrayExpectant`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what are you trying to accomplish, but I think this is bad and very confusing code.

You seem to be using the interface `IEquatable<T>` to mean “`T`, or a type that has some relation to `T`”. That's not what it's meant for at all!

Also, the point of interfaces is to be able to use different types in the same way. For example, if I have a `IEnumerable<string>`, I know I can iterate over it using a `foreach` and process the `string`s it gives me.

But that does not apply to your interface. I have to know whether I have have `Simpleton<T>` (I have to pass `T` to it) or `ArrayExpectant<T>` (I have to pass `ArrayWrapper<T>` to it).

Because of this, I would suggest you to drop the interface completely, I don't see any benefit of having it.